# D3.js problem with mousedown events on dashed lines and markers

Tags: d3.js

Using d3.js. I am creating a dashed line with a triangular marker which has a mousedown event.

The event triggers when I click on the line but NOT:

- If I click on the gaps between the dashes.
- If I click on the marker (a large triangle)

Can either of these problems be resolved?

*I realise that the dotted problem could be solved by creating an invisible undotted line over the line I am creating and code on that; but that seems to be a non-elegant solution. It would also not solve the marker-end issue.*

`svg.append('path').attr('id', tid).attr('d', cline(data)).attr('fill', 'none').attr('stroke', linecol).attr('stroke-width', 5).attr('marker-end', 'url(#' + site + '_arrow)').style('stroke-dasharray', '9 6').on('mousedown', this.selectmousedown);`

[image: Dotted line with marker-end]

Answer (score 0):

The first clear issue is that your `fill` is `none`. You could either set your `fill` to match the background color or set the `fill` to something else but also set the `fill-opacity` to zero. Here's an example:

```js
let svg = d3.select('#viz').append('svg')

let T1 = svg
    .append("path")
    .attr("d",
      d3.line()([
        [10, 10],
        [110, 10],
        [110, 110]
      ])
    )
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
    .on("click", () => console.log("clicked first"));
 svg.append('text')
   .attr('x', 10)
   .attr('y', 130)
   .text('Reacts to click')

let T2 = svg
    .append("path")
    .attr("d",
      d3.line()([
        [160, 10],
        [260, 10],
        [260, 110]
      ])
    )
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .on("click", () => console.log("clicked second"));
svg.append('text')
   .attr('x', 180)
   .attr('y', 130)
   .text('Does not')
```

```html
<div id="viz"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but that does not work. The exact code I tried was...   svg.append('path').attr('id', shapeid).attr('d', tcline).attr('fill', 'red').attr('fill-opacity', 0).attr('stroke', '#00FF00').attr('stroke-width', 5).style('stroke-dasharray', '9 6').on('mousedown', this.selectmousedown);

Comment: To be clear, the fact that your `fill` is `none` definitely *is* an issue. It's also the only definitive issue that I see in the code. I've posted complete code to illustrate. It's hard to say what other issues might exist in your code without complete code, rather than just a snippet. Another *possible* issue is what's going on with `this.selectmousedown`? Presumably, it should be a function. I don't know what it actually is, though.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update your response. I have added an image to clarify that it is only a line that I am clicking on; not an area.